# Undefined method `stub_model' error with rspec

Tags: rspec, devise

spec helper:

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause this
# file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, make a
# separate helper file that requires this one and then use it only in the specs
# that actually need it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.

require 'capybara/rspec'

# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234

  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
#    mocks.syntax = :expect

    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

spec (spec/views/devise_spec):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'devise/registrations/new', js: true, type: :view do



    it 'has a name field' do
      assign(:widgets, [
        stub_model(User, :name => "slicer"),
        stub_model(User, :name => "dicer")
      ])

      resource = double('User')
      render


      rendered.should contain('Email')
    end

end
```

Result:

```
  1) devise/registrations/new has a name field
     Failure/Error: stub_model(User, :name => "slicer"),
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stub_model' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::DeviseRegistrationsNew:0x007fa8f0b761a0>
     # ./spec/views/devise_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.21879 seconds (files took 2.05 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/devise_spec.rb:7 # devise/registrations/new has a name field

Top 4 slowest examples (0.21735 seconds, 99.3% of total time):
  user page registration responds with sign in page
    0.1512 seconds ./spec/requests/user_spec.rb:12
  user page registration responds with sign up page
    0.05601 seconds ./spec/requests/user_spec.rb:6
  Static pages responds with home page
    0.0087 seconds ./spec/requests/static_spec.rb:4
  devise/registrations/new has a name field
    0.00144 seconds ./spec/views/devise_spec.rb:7

Top 3 slowest example groups:
  user page
    0.10361 seconds average (0.20721 seconds / 2 examples) ./spec/requests/user_spec.rb:3
  Static pages
    0.0087 seconds average (0.0087 seconds / 1 example) ./spec/requests/static_spec.rb:3
  devise/registrations/new
    0.00144 seconds average (0.00144 seconds / 1 example) ./spec/views/devise_spec.rb:3

Randomized with seed 12448
```

Followed all rspec instructions. This is a devise view that needs to mock the vague 'resource' variable I know nothing about...

Answer (score 1):

As of RSpec 3.0.0.rc1, the `stub_model` method has been extracted to a separate gem, `rspec-activerecord-mocks`, as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/changelog.